# Regex in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have been trying to extract text with =REGEXREPLACE() in Google Sheets.
The aim is to split the string after every third sentence. I achieved this in regex101 with the following formula: (.*?). (.*?). (.*?). and substitution of \1. \2. \3.\r\n\r\n.

Heres an example of the string I am trying to separate:

I am a sentence. I am another sentence. Another random sentence to add to the mix. Once again I find myself writing a sentence. I hope this weekend is sunny in Brisbane. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The cat crept into the crypt, crapped and crept out again. There are never enough hours in a day. Streaming GeorgeFM from Auckland via the bose soundtouch app is the beez kneez. For good measure, I thought I would write another sentence.

Using the above I have managed to achieve:

I am a sentence. I am another sentence. Another random sentence to add to the mix.

Once again I find myself writing a sentence. I hope this weekend is sunny in Brisbane. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

The cat crept into the crypt, crapped and crept out again. There are never enough hours in a day. Streaming GeorgeFM from Auckland via the bose soundtouch app is the beez kneez.

For good measure, I thought I would write another sentence.

Issues:
it does not trim the whitespace at the beginning of sentences and;
it does not work at all in google sheets!

Below are the links to Regex101 and Google Sheets.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BFFvqV/4).

[Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yqw4yK4D2O5_0XAzuFtjG3r1BUWJ7i05OZgCcLsY4T8/edit?usp=sharing).

Any ideas?

Many thanks.
Ross

Answer (score 0):

change `\1.\2.\3.` to `$1.$2.$3` to get the replace working in google sheets.

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45080851/9534819), we cannot use regex in the replace string, hence \r\n will not work in the replace.

Adding a `*` (space followed by *) at the beginning of the regex fixes the space issue.

Regex: `*(.*?)\. (.*?)\. (.*?)\.`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BFFvqV/5)

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for taking the time to respond. Problem solved. I ammended the replace string as follows: "$1. $2. $3. "&char(10)&char(10). Works great.